# how does one transform / change the perspective of an image in titanium to provide 3D effect

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to create a 3D effect in Titanium for an image.

can you please provide pointers on how to make an image that looks like

[image]

to look like

[image]

I looked at transform, create2dmatrix etc - but the documentation is not too clear for me.

```
 var image2 = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: '/giraffe.jpg',
    height: '323',
    width: "270",
    left: "1px",
    });
```

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. after struggling with trying to understand the documentation, the following expriment fixed it for me.

```
var image2 = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
image: '/giraffe.jpg',
height: '323',
width: "270",
left: "1px",
});

t.m34 = 1.0/1000;
t = t.rotate (20,0,1,0);
t = t.rotate (20,0,1,0);
img.transform = t ;
```

and everything works fine..